# How to wrap React component with little performance penalty?

Tags: reactjs, performance, material-ui

My team uses React [MaterialUI](https://material-ui-next.com/) library. To provide consistent UI Pattern and make it easy for us to customise MaterialUI's component, we wrap each MaterialUI's component in our own component. For example:

```
const style = {} // our project custom style for ListItemText
const OurListItemText = ({primary, secondary, classes}: Props) => (
  <MuiListItemText
    primary={primary}
    secondary={secondary}
    className={classes.text}
  />
) // we only expose primary and secondary props of the original MuiListItemText.
// Team members are blocked from customising other MUIListItemText's props

export default withStyles(styles)(OurListItemText)
```

`MuiListItemText` is the original [MaterialUI](https://material-ui-next.com/)'s component, while `OurListItemText` is our wrapper component. In our project, **only** `OurListItemText` is allowed to be used.

As the snippet above, `OurListItemText` does nothing but forward the props to `MuiListItemText`. However, this affects the performance quite a lot:

[image: React Flame graph]

`ListItemText` bar on the top is from `OurListItemText` while the one below is from `MuiListItemText`. If we use `MuiListItemText` directly, it could be ~50% faster (we have tried), which is noticeable when we have 100 `ListItemText`. Removing `withStyles` HOC improves a bit, but not significantly.

`ListItemText` is only one example, we have similar performance issue on other wrapped components. (2 `Typography` in the graph above is another pair of our-wrapper-component and MUI's-original-component)

How to improve the performance of those simple props-forwarding-components?

Comment: There's not much you can do to improve performances except not wrapping them. I'm surprised this is a problem for you, do you feel it's slow or just see it takes time in the debugger? We don't see any ms in the screenshot above. Also are you testing in production mode?

Comment: Also, this might help improve performances a bit: https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-react-optimize

Comment: Yes, we also tested in production mode with Babel React optimize. As we have a list with 100s items, the speed diff is between 1.x seconds (with wrapper) to 0.5 seconds (without). The diff is quite significant for UX

Comment: @PahleviFikriAuliya I second SebastianLorber--why not remove the HOC and create just one component? Then you only pass props once and simplify the render tree. Also, why not move styles to CSS to get it out of the JS thread? That should improve performance a touch (you can see the cost of the `withStyles()` calls pretty easily). I'd drop Material altogether--it's essentially just some CSS, which should be implemented in CSS (for GPU acceleration) with minimal components rendering the appropriate CSS classes; there's no need for Material components at all...

Comment: That requires a lot of changes. Initially we thought wrapping component should not cost a lot. The same analogy as calling one extra layer of function should only cost a little. But it turns out, wrapping a React component adds one extra level of full React lifecycle (i.e. the wrapper needs to be mounted). Is it possible to avoid this?

Answer (score 6):

> wrapping a React component adds one extra level of full React lifecycle (i.e. the wrapper needs to be mounted). Is it possible to avoid this?

You can avoid the lifecycles by avoiding JSX and calling the functions directly instead.
Eg.

```
{Component({ data: 1, children: 'Hello' })}
```

instead of

```
<Component data={1}>Hello</Component>
```

[This blog post](https://medium.com/missive-app/45-faster-react-functional-components-now-3509a668e69f) claimed to achieve 45% speed improvement with their test case.

This syntax might not be as readable/understandable though.

Some quote from [Dan Abramov regarding this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12066):

> We're looking at optimizations like this in the context of Prepack but there's nothing that's going to be immediately useable in the next couple of months. Within a year or two we might have something.
>
> Note that unless you're creating thousands of elements, the performance difference won't be noticeable. Also unless your components are very flat and simple, the "pure win" from this optimization will likely be much less relevant in practice.

I wouldn't wait for Prepack to do the optimisation though since the timeline is uncertain and the resulting optimisation might not be identical to this.

As for the significance of the performance improvement, it'd depend on your project and the only way to be certain is to try out and see the improvement for yourself.

Comment: The blog post is written for an older version of React. I read it a few days ago and got really impressed, though couldn't find any similar comparison for newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want raw performance - do not wrap ListItem, but write your replacement instead

[List item source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/ListItem/ListItem.js) doesn't have any extra dependencies, so Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V will work

Then adjust for your needs, remove code you don't need, etc...

That will guarantee max possible performance

---

*The negative side - support cost will grow.*