# Is it possible to get ref of props.children?

Tags: reactjs

I want to get ref of Child component. What is the best way to do this?

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Child</div>;
  }
}   

class GetRef extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
     console.log(this.props.children.ref)
  }


  render() {
    return this.props.children
  }
}
```

Edit:
So I can use it like this

```
<GetRef><Child/></GetRef>
```

Comment: what is the link between Child and GetRef ?

Comment: What exactly are you needing to accomplish?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé I have added an example

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assumed that `GetRef` children has only **one** child, then you can retrieve the ref of the only `child` component with this code

```
class Child extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <div>Child</div>;
  }
}  

class GetRef extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.ref);
  }

  render() {
    const childElement = React.Children.only(this.props.children);

    return React.cloneElement(
      childElement, 
      { ref: el => this.ref = el }
    );
  }

}

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return <GetRef><Child/></GetRef>;
  }

}
```

Here is the [complete example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bsmrci) on stackblitz

If `this.props.children` has more than one child, you will need to iterate over the children and store all the `refs` into an array

Comment: This destroys the `ref` prop that the child may have already had, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is where [forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) can be used:

```
class GetRef extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.forwardRef)
    }
}

const ref = React.createRef();
<Child forwardRef={ref} />
```

---

Alternatively, you may also use:

```
<Child ref="childRef" .../>


// In the parent component
React.findDOMNode(this.refs.childRef)
```

---

But take a look at [Exposing DOM Refs to Parent Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#exposing-dom-refs-to-parent-components) to know whether to use ref or not:

> In rare cases, you might want to have access to a child’s DOM node from a parent component. This is generally not recommended because it breaks component encapsulation, but it can occasionally be useful for triggering focus or measuring the size or position of a child DOM node.