# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string in react ,when trying to update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got this error when updating state from fetch.

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

This is my code below

```js
import React  from "react"
import useState from "react"
import {
  Button,
  Progress,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownItem,
  Input,
Badge,
Row,
Col,
 ListGroup,
  ListGroupItem
} from "reactstrap";
import Draggable from 'react-draggable'
import StatisticsCard from "../../components/@vuexy/statisticsCard/StatisticsCard"
import DataTable from "react-data-table-component"
import classnames from "classnames"
import ReactPaginate from "react-paginate"
import { history } from "../../history"
import {
  Edit,
  Trash,
  ChevronDown,
  Plus,
  Check,
  ChevronLeft,
  ChevronRight,
 Monitor,
  UserCheck,
  Mail,
  Eye,
  MessageSquare,
  ShoppingBag,
  Heart,
  Smile,
  Truck,
  Cpu,
  Server,
  Activity,
  AlertOctagon,
CreditCard,
Share,
Image
} from "react-feather"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import {
  getData,
  getInitialData,
  deleteData,
  updateData,
  addData,
  filterData
} from "../../redux/actions/data-list/"
import Sidebar from "./DataListSidebar"
import Chip from "../../components/@vuexy/chips/ChipComponent"
import Checkbox from "../../components/@vuexy/checkbox/CheckboxesVuexy"

import "../../assets/scss/plugins/extensions/react-paginate.scss"
import "../../assets/scss/pages/data-list.scss"
import { Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from 'reactstrap';
import NumberFormat from 'react-number-format';
import $ from 'jquery'
import tc from 'thousands-counter';
 

 

class DataListConfig extends React.Component  {


 constructor(props){
 super(props)
 
 
  this.state = {
    data: [],
    campaigns: [],
    tt: 0,
    totalPages: 0,
    currentPage: 0,
    columns: [
      {
        name: "Name",
        selector: "name",
        sortable: true,
        cell: row => (
          <p title={row.name} className="text-truncate text-bold-500 mb-0">
            {sessionStorage.Name}
          </p>
        )
      },
       {
        name: "Title",
        selector: "title",
        sortable: true,
        cell: row => (
          <p className="text-bold-500 text-truncate mb-0">{row.title}</p>
        )
      },
      
            {
        name: "Total Donation",
        selector: "totaldonor",
        sortable: true,
        cell: row => (
          <p className="text-bold-500 text-truncate mb-0"> <NumberFormat value={row.amounts} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'₦'} /></p>
        )
      },
      {
        name: "Status",
        selector: "status",
        sortable: true,
        cell: row => (
          <Badge
            color={row.status === null || row.status === '' ? "light-danger" : "light-success"}
            pill>
           {row.status === null || row.status === '' ? "Pending":"Active"}
          </Badge>
        )
      },
      
       {
        name: "Start Date",
        selector: "startdate",
        sortable: true,
        cell: row => <p className="text-bold-500 mb-0">{row.startdate}</p>
      },
      {
        name: "Category",
        selector: "category",
        sortable: true,
        cell: row => <p className="text-bold-500 mb-0">{row.category}</p>
      },
      {
        name: "Actions",
        sortable: true,
        cell: row => (
        <this.ActionsComponent
            row={row}
            getData={this.props.getData}
            parsedFilter={this.props.parsedFilter}
            currentData={this.handleCurrentData}
            deleteRow={this.handleDelete}
          />

        )
      }
    ],
    allData: [],
    value: "",
    comments:[],
    rowsPerPage: 4,
    sidebar: false,
    currentData: null,
    selected: [],
    totalRecords: 0,
    sortIndex: [],
    addNew: ""
  }
  const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' , 'Authorization':`Bearer ${sessionStorage.jwt}`}
    fetch(' ', { headers })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
        
    
   
             
    this.setState({ data: data.posts })
 
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
});


 }
 
  componentDidMount()
{
 
function ActionsComponent(props) {


        



 
  const {
    buttonLabel,
    className
  } = props;
const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
const [modal2, setModal2] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
 const [comments,setCom] = useState([])
 
 const Details = (id)=> {
 
 $.post(' ',{
 
 postid: id
 },function(data,status){
  
setItems([
      ...items,
      {
        datas: data
       
      }
    ]);

  
 })
 

  
 }
 

  $.post(' ',{
 
 postid: props.row.id
 },function(data,status){
   
 
this.setState({commets: data})

  
 })
 
 


 
 let datas
 datas = {totaldonors: "",totalcomments:""}
  items.map((key)=>{
 datas = key.datas
  })
 
const dashdata = datas
 


  const toggleModal = (id) =>{ setModal(!modal); };
 const toggleModal2 = (id) =>{ setModal2(!modal2); };
 
  return (
  

  <div>
    <Draggable>
 <Modal
        isOpen={modal}
        toggle={toggleModal}
        className="modal-dialog-centered"
        backdrop={false}
      >
        <ModalHeader toggle={toggleModal}>
          Campaign Dashboard!
        </ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody className="modal-dialog-centered">
  
 <div className="container">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-sm">
    <StatisticsCard
              hideChart
              iconBg="primary"
              icon={<CreditCard className="primary" size={22} />}
              stat={tc(dashdata.totaldonors)}
              statTitle="Total Donors"
            />
    </div>
    <div className="col-sm">
    <StatisticsCard
              hideChart
              iconBg="primary"
              icon={<Share className="primary" size={22} />}
              stat="36.9k"
              statTitle="Total Shares"
            />
    </div>
    <div className="col-sm">
    <StatisticsCard
              hideChart
              iconBg="primary"
              icon={<MessageSquare className="primary" size={22} />}
              stat={tc(dashdata.totalcomments)}
              statTitle="Total Comments"
            />
    </div>
<div className="container" style={{'max-height':'300px','overflow-y': 'scroll'}}>

 
</div>
  </div>

</div>


  
        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
          <Button color="primary">
         Request Withdrawal
          </Button>{" "}
        </ModalFooter>
      </Modal>

                    </Draggable>
                    
                    
                       

    <div className="data-list-action">
    {" "}
    {" "}
      <Edit
        className="cursor-pointer mr-1"
        size={20}
        onClick={() => {
          return props.currentData(props.row)
        }}
      />

 <Activity
        className="cid cursor-pointer mr-1"
        size={20}
          onClick={()=>{return toggleModal(),Details(props.row.id);}}
      />
      
    </div>

</div>

  )

}
 
     
}


  thumbView = this.props.thumbView

 

 

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.thumbView) {
      this.thumbView = false
      let  columns =  [
      {
        name: "Name",
        selector: "name",
        sortable: true,
        cell: row => (
          <p title={row.name} className="text-truncate text-bold-500 mb-0">
            {sessionStorage.Name}
          </p>
        )
      },
       {
        name: "Title",
        selector: "title",
        sortable: true,
        cell: row => (
          <p className="text-bold-500 text-truncate mb-0">{row.title}</p>
        )
      },
      {
        name: "Status",
        selector: "status",
        sortable: true,
        cell: row => (
          <Badge
            color={row.status === null || row.status === '' ? "light-danger" : "light-success"}
            pill>
           {row.status === null || row.status === '' ? "Pending":"Active"}
          </Badge>
        )
      },
            {
        name: "Total Donation",
        selector: "totaldonor",
        sortable: true,
        cell: row => (
          <p className="text-bold-500 text-truncate mb-0">{row.amounts}</p>
        )
      },
      
       {
        name: "Start Date",
        selector: "startdate",
        sortable: true,
        cell: row => <p className="text-bold-500 mb-0">{row.startdate}</p>
      },
      {
        name: "Category",
        selector: "category",
        sortable: true,
        cell: row => <p className="text-bold-500 mb-0">{row.category}</p>
      },
       
      {
          name: "Actions",
          sortable: true,
          cell: row => (
            <this.ActionsComponent
              row={row}
              getData={this.props.getData}
              parsedFilter={this.props.parsedFilter}
              currentData={this.handleCurrentData}
              deleteRow={this.handleDelete}
            />
             
          )
        }
      ]
      this.setState({ columns })
    }
  }

  handleFilter = e => {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value })
    this.props.filterData(e.target.value)
  }

  handleRowsPerPage = value => {
    let { parsedFilter, getData } = this.props
    let page = parsedFilter.page !== undefined ? parsedFilter.page : 1
    history.push(`/funding/?page=${page}&perPage=${value}`)
    this.setState({ rowsPerPage: value })
    getData({ page: parsedFilter.page, perPage: value })
  }

  handleSidebar = (boolean, addNew = false) => {
    this.setState({ sidebar: boolean })
    if (addNew === true) this.setState({ currentData: null, addNew: true })
  }

  handleDelete = row => {
    this.props.deleteData(row)
    this.props.getData(this.props.parsedFilter)
    if (this.state.data.length - 1 === 0) {
      let urlPrefix = this.props.thumbView
        ? "/funding/"
        : "/funding/"
      history.push(
        `${urlPrefix}list-view?page=${parseInt(
          this.props.parsedFilter.page - 1
        )}&perPage=${this.props.parsedFilter.perPage}`
      )
      this.props.getData({
        page: this.props.parsedFilter.page - 1,
        perPage: this.props.parsedFilter.perPage
      })
    }
  }

  handleCurrentData = obj => {
    this.setState({ currentData: obj })
    this.handleSidebar(true)
  }

  handlePagination = page => {
    let { parsedFilter, getData } = this.props
    let perPage = parsedFilter.perPage !== undefined ? parsedFilter.perPage : 4
 
    let urlPrefix = this.props.thumbView
      ? "/funding/b"
      : "/funding/"
    history.push(
      `${urlPrefix}?page=${page.selected + 1}&perPage=${perPage}`
    )
    getData({ page: page.selected + 1, perPage: perPage })
 
 
    this.setState({ currentPage: page.selected })
  }

  render() {
    let {
      columns,
      data,
      allData,
      totalPages,
      value,
      rowsPerPage,
      currentData,
      sidebar,
      totalRecords,
      sortIndex
    } = this.state
    

    return (
      <div
        className={`data-list ${
          this.props.thumbView ? "thumb-view" : "list-view"
        }`}>
<CustomHeader
handleSidebar={this.handleSidebar}
              handleFilter={this.handleFilter}
              handleRowsPerPage={this.handleRowsPerPage}
              rowsPerPage="5"
              total={totalRecords}
              index={sortIndex}
/>
        <DataTable
          columns={columns}
          data={data}
          pagination

          noHeader
          
          selectableRows
          responsive
          pointerOnHover
          selectableRowsHighlight
          onSelectedRowsChange={data =>
            this.setState({ selected: data.selectedRows })
          }
          customStyles={selectedStyle}
          subHeaderComponent={
            <CustomHeader
              handleSidebar={this.handleSidebar}
              handleFilter={this.handleFilter}
              handleRowsPerPage={this.handleRowsPerPage}
              rowsPerPage="5"
              total={totalRecords}
              index={sortIndex}
            />
          }
          sortIcon={<ChevronDown />}
          selectableRowsComponent={Checkbox}
          selectableRowsComponentProps={{
            color: "primary",
            icon: <Check className="vx-icon" size={12} />,
            label: "",
            size: "sm"
          }}
        />
        <Sidebar
          show={sidebar}
          data={currentData}
          updateData={this.props.updateData}
          addData={this.props.addData}
          handleSidebar={this.handleSidebar}
          thumbView={this.props.thumbView}
          getData={this.props.getData}
          dataParams={this.props.parsedFilter}
          addNew={this.state.addNew}
        />
        <div
          className={classnames("data-list-overlay", {
            show: sidebar
          })}
          onClick={() => this.handleSidebar(false, true)}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    dataList: state.dataList
  }
}

const   handleSidebar = (boolean, addNew = false) => {
    this.setState({ sidebar: boolean })
    if (addNew === true) this.setState({ currentData: null, addNew: true })
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getData,
  deleteData,
  updateData,
  addData,
  getInitialData,
  filterData
})(DataListConfig)
```

i removed my api endpoint for security purpose

[bug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDRtj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataListConfig` component tries to render `<this.ActionsComponent>`. Because `ActionsComponent` is defined inside the `componentDidMount` method, instead of at the class level, `this.ActionsComponent` is undefined. Which causes the error.

Ultimately though defining a component inside another component is a bad idea. Inside a class component's class as a field, it will mean that each instance of that class component [will have their own version of the function component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657062/functional-components-inside-class-components). This smells fishy at best, and is not very React-like.

Move `ActionsComponent` outside the `DataListConfig` component entirely, and pass in data it needs through its props.

```
function ActionsComponent(props) {
  // ...
}

class DataListConfig extends React.Component {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: how do i set state inside the function, is that possible?

Comment: @silexsecurelab You pass a callback function which sets the state in the parent component to the component via props. See the [React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up) for examples (especially the part where they pass `onClick` to `<Square>`)