# user-defined component in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

Why does 'element' define what looks like an HTML tag that call's a function.
Why would i not set element to something like: Welcome('Sara')

```
function Welcome(props) {  
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}

const element = <Welcome name="Sara" />;

ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Comment: Its because you're writing React using jsx; which is the suggested way. If you want to learn what is going on in the background, here's a link: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html.

Answer (score 0):

The format resembling HTML is called [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html):

> it is a syntax extension to JavaScript. We recommend using it with
> React to describe what the UI should look like

Technically (in this simple case) you could replace the JSX with `Welcome({ name: 'Sara' })`, but that is not the standard way to render components in React - and it has some [technical implications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52212946/4722345) because it is not the same as using JSX (which [calls](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html) [React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)).