# How to test a React component with multiple child components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I cut out all my code to the area of interest (so pardon if the code looks like it's trying to do nothing), but essentially when I pass in a couple `<Navbar.Tab comopnent={null}/>` into `<Navbar></Navbar>` and attempt to unit test it using Jest and Enzyme, the React.Children.count can see that there are > 1 children, but when it comes to `.type()` it cannot understand it and this error is prompted. The component renders fine, I just don't know how to test it.

```
 Navbar component › Rendered navbar with many non tabs

    TypeError: child.type is not a function

      48 |   if (React.Children.count(children) > 1) {
      49 |     value = children.map(child => {
    > 50 |       isTab = child.type().toLowerCase() !== 'tabs' ? false : isTab;
         |                     ^
      51 |       return child.props;
      52 |     });
      53 |   }
```

navbar

```
const Navbar = ({ children, filter }) => {
  let isTab = true;
  let value = null;
  if (React.Children.count(children) > 1) {
    value = children.map(child => {
      isTab = child.type().toLowerCase() !== 'tabs' ? false : isTab;
      return child.props;
    });
  }
  return (
    <>
      {value.map(child => child.component)}
    </>
  )
}

const Tabs = () => {
  return 'tabs';
};
Navbar.Tab = Tabs;
export default Navbar;
```

navbar.test.js

```
 test('Rendered navbar with filter', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Navbar filter>
        <Navbar.Tab label="In Flight Orders" component={null} />,
        <Navbar.Tab label="Active Service" component={null} />,
        <Navbar.Tab label="Active Service 1" component={null} />
      </Navbar>
    );
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

Comment: Please, provide `Rendered navbar with many non tabs` in the question. It contains only another test that will likely not cause the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`child.type().toLowerCase() !== 'tabs'` is a bad way to do this check. Not every child element is React component, and not every class or functional React component is allowed to be called like a function. It's [unsafe hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047063/direct-call-of-a-functional-component) that will result in error for almost every child except `Tab`. `type` should be compared against `Tab` instead.

The component will also fail if `value === null`.

A safer and simpler way to write it is:

```
const Navbar = ({ children, filter }) => {
  const tabs = React.Children.toArray(children)
  .filter(child => child.type === Navbar.Tab)
  .map(child => child.props.component)
  .filter(Boolean);

  return (
    <>
      {tabs}
    </>
  )
}
```